# (How) Do journals keep kook papers from clogging up the review system?

Tags: publications, peer-review

I have written two papers and submitted them to two different journals, and in both instances the process was as simple as registering an account and uploading the paper. While this system was quite convenient and in the spirit of open sharing of knowledge, I can't help but notice that any kook could stick their paper into the publication pipeline.

I looked at [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/10612/70552), which tells me how the kook publication would be caught by the peer review process. However, this means that some time and resources have been allotted to finding the reviewers and the reviewers have at least looked at the paper, and maybe even taken the time to replicate the experiment.

So, my question is: what sort of safeguards, if any, are usually in place to keep kook papers from tying up resources?

Comment: The first two papers I was asked to review were crank papers for respectable journals. So perhaps the answer includes "throw reviews at inexperienced graduate student reviewers."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Desk rejection by the editor..

Comment: That's a big part of it, surely.  But I still wonder how the editors of some journals do anything other than desk reject kook papers.

Comment: Maybe they have assistant editors wygodę only responsibility is filtering out kook papers?