# Crackpot research paper in mathematics

Tags: publications, mathematics, peer-review, journals

How does a math journal react to a crackpot math research paper?
In mathematics (especially in Number Theory) there are many meaningless papers on the web, and possibly a ton of meaningless submissions. Also, how does a journal react when a proof of a major unsolved problems, such as the 'Riemann Hypothesis', is submitted?

Comment: As an editor, I'd immediately reject these papers. If the paper made enough sense to have an identifiable error (or small set of errors), I might point out the error(s); this is often but not always useless. If the paper was just nonsense, I'd just reject it.  (One exception: A journal promised blind refereeing, so I felt obligated to ask for a report from a referee who hadn't seen the author's name. I shouldn't have felt that way.)

Comment: As an aside, see the book *Mathematical Cranks* by Underwood Dudley.  Also *The Trisectors* by the same author.

Comment: Why should a journal not carefully vet a paper no matter whether it solves a long-standing, major problem or makes a minor contribution? If the Riemann Hypothesis is a problem for which a proof theoretically could exist, then one day the first paper must contain the proof. Disclaimer: I'm not a mathematician, I don't know this field.

Comment: @MathiasMüller: because the limit on time that the journal has to vet papers is lower than the corresponding limit on time that crackpots have to generate them. When faced with an argument that has no mathematical merit, it doesn't necessarily take careful vetting to see this. The tiny risk of missing a paper that has some merit, but fails to make it obvious, is justified by the value of redirecting resources towards submissions with obvious merit.

Comment: Also note that although what Andreas said might be taken to mean that he would immediately reject any paper claiming to prove the Riemann Hypothesis, this may not be *strictly* true. The way mathematics actually works, we know a lot of results in and around the Riemann Hypothesis that mean almost certainly there will never actually be a "first paper to contain the proof". What there could well be, as with Fermat's Last Theorem or the Poincaré conjecture, is a first paper to *complete* the proof.

Comment: Related: [(How) Do journals keep kook papers from clogging up the review system?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/89491/70552)

Comment: But I say "almost" certainly: an elementary proof in a single paper is conceivable, just not likely enough to justify spending time on a potentially-unlimited quantity of utter nonsense. The fact that mathematical journals exist does not entitle me to submit 26MB of randomly-genereated ASCII text and expect a journal editor to read it carefully just in case it contains a proof of the Goldbach Conjecture.

Comment: @SteveJessop I think you are implying that bogus papers are long and difficult to comprehend. If a paper is unbearably long I believe it should be rejected based on its length, not because it claims to prove a major problem. Right?

Comment: @MathiasMüller As the author of several >100 pages papers, I disagree :) (I *swear* we tried to make them shorter)

Comment: @SteveJessop Sorry for the sloppiness of my comment. I meant that I'd immediately reject papers that I can see are crackpot papers. An alleged proof of the Riemann Hypothesis might not fall into that category.

Comment: **Please don’t write answers in comments.** It bypasses our quality measures by not having voting (both up and down) available on comments, as well as having other problems [detailed on meta](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1644/11811). Andreas, Steve -- please consider converting your comments into answers; they seem like good answers that would be well received.

Comment: @DenisNardin Yes, good papers can be long. But that is a truism and a straw man to the actual discussion (How do journals react to a bogus paper?). The [comment by Andreas](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/162044/crackpot-research-paper-in-mathematics?noredirect=1#comment435856_162044) and [answer by Dan](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/162111/23803) make it clear how editors handle this has nothing to do with length, or with the nature of the problem being solved: editors use a set of heuristics to quickly determine whether a paper is meaningless.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Indeed that was what I wanted to communicate with my comment (that there are better heuristics than length to judge the quality of a paper). Sorry if it didn't come across clearly.

Comment: Have a look at the infamous "proof" that 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... = -1/12.  The conclusion is obviously false and absurd on the face of it, and a bit of analysis shows that the result is obtained by throwing a step containing undefined behavior into the middle of it, (the same trick as the high school algebra "proofs" that show that 1 = 2 by cleverly hiding a division by 0 in a long sequence of calculations,) and yet you can still find plenty of respectable outlets claiming that this gibberish is a proven fact.

Comment: @cag51: I believe that my responses are not an answer, since they don't say how journals react to crackpot papers. Rather, they answer Matthias's separate question in comments, why journals are justified to react as they do. I appreciate that StackExchange does not actually permit helping people with ad hoc questions, and the conversation will probably get rolled up at some point :-)

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Ramanujan summation is actually a different trick from sneakily dividing by zero to get any answer you like. But sure, just saying "shove it into the zeta function" is not a proper construction and proof of the properties of Ramanujan summation.

Comment: @SteveJessop "The same trick" in the sense of "it's hiding undefined behavior in the middle of the so-called proof."  The specific piece of undefined behavior used here is different, that's true, but it's still the same trick.

Comment: @MathiasMüller In case of *crackpot* submissions as literally referenced by the OP, such papers often are so bad that they are "not even wrong", or the author starts by clumsily defining zero

Comment: Out of pure curiousity , does mathematics get much in the way of crankery? I know there are some fields that are utter crank magnets (physics, archeology, medicine being notable)  but math?

Comment: @Shayne A huge amount of it, especially in fields that have (apparently) not much technical backround, or that are "trendy" (i.e. they are frequently covered in pop math articles). After all it's a subject where you can literally do research using only pen and paper, the barrier to access is quite minimal.

Comment: I briefly moderated Physics space on Quora, prior to resigning in protest at the admins turning the 2mil+ member physics space into "the science place". And *oh boy* did we get wingnuts. One guy re-regged hundreds of accounts to spam his theory that gravity is "displaced dark matter". Lots of guys who "made a website that disproves science, one interesting whacko with his mathematically interesting but nonsensical "hypergeometric universs" and the notoriously bonkers Amed M'Bark who.. well nobody could quite work out what his theory was but boy did he like spamming it.

Comment: read that as "a website that disproves einstein". 6am pre-coffee posting makes for weird errors.

Answer (score 42):

Here are the basic mechanisms that I know of, having only limited experience on an editorial board.

The first is a classic desk rejection.  This is where the editor who makes the initial assessment, just says no, without asking for referees.  This has to happen, or one gets flooded with AI generated nonsense as a joke.

Some journals insist that you list a few potential referees.  I believe that one of the reasons they do this is to see if you have interactions (even just closely reading their papers) with mathematicians.  If the author of a number theory paper list as potential referees three Fields medalists from three different areas of mathematics, probably they have no idea what they are doing.  Makes a desk reject easier.

The second is the editor asks for a quick opinion from a mathematician in vaguely the correct area, asking if the paper is worth refereeing.  You can tell if you get this type of rejection sometimes as the editor says after a few weeks something like "the feedback I have gotten are that this is out of scope for our journal." So I have heard.  From a friend.

Finally there is just sending it to one or more reviewers.  If the editor needs one referee, asks four in succession and they all say no, then the editor is likely to reject the paper.

There are problems with these methods.  Some innovative work is hard to classify, and a paper gets rejected because the editor asks all the wrong people.  I had a paper go to a topic editor, go out for review, then get assigned to another topic editor, out for several reviews.  It finally landed on the correct reviewer, but this could easily have gotten rejected.

Comment: *Some journals insist that you list a few potential referees. I believe that one of the reasons they do this is to see if you have interactions with mathematicians* I used to be a physicist and had my fair share of lunatics coming to me with new theories. I had two cases of people who came with an innovative approach in a rather niche area and they did not know anyone in the field. Their papers ended up being published. So I hope that this requirement can be waived (when correctly explained) because it may, in these rare cases, be a show stopper for some.

Comment: Judging a paper based on the suggested referees, rather than the content of the paper, is outright corrupt.  Do not do it.

Comment: @WoJ I got around the problem you propose by picking a few names from related papers in the same journal (actually, you might make dealing with that a separate question).

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Is corrupt really the right word? What does an editor personally gain from judging a paper by its suggested referees? I agree a paper should be judged by its content, but suggested referees still seems like a useful data point to contextualize the paper. If an author cannot describe how their work fits into the field at large, or name anyone who has worked on similar problems, I'd certainly look at their manuscript with a more critical eye, since the author has evidently not judged themselves in the context of the relevant body of work.

Comment: @WoJ Do you mean that they did not know anyone *personally* in the field, or that they did not know the name of anyone working in the field? In the latter case, even assuming that someone could make innovative research without being familiar with the past work, it can be easily fixed with a cursory literature search...

Comment: @DenisNardin: yes, I meant personally. In retrospect, I see that the intent of the request is to suggest *appropriate* reviewers, rather than ones that one knows personally. This indeed makes sense to check if some has an idea of who works in the field.

Comment: The list of suggested referees is just one data point an editor might use.  Another might be reasonable looking references and an intelligible abstract.  When in doubt, one should send for refereeing.

Comment: @WoJ I edited the answer to specify why I mean by interactions with mathematicians.  Just reading recent papers, meeting at a conference, or knowing a bit about them through your advisor.

Comment: @DenisNardin - I thought the point of the suggestion was that the typical crank would not have even done such a literature search ...

Comment: @davidbak Indeed, that's what I wanted to point out in my comment: I'm sure the people in the case WoJ talked about would not have had any problems suggesting names of relevant people (and indeed it seems like they misunderstood the requirement).

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Yes, corrupt in the sense of "rotten" or "immoral" is the right word.  Corrupt sometimes, but not always, means that an improper benefit is received.  So that's not a requirement for something to be corrupt.

Comment: "If an author cannot describe how their work fits into the field at large, or name anyone who has worked on similar problems,"  That's not the same as suggesting reviewers.

Answer (score 29):

A famous number theorist once told me he receives approximately one submission a week claiming to prove the Riemann Hypothesis at the top journal where he is an editor. Thus the need to conscientiously and in good faith evaluate such submissions is a real drain on his time and the time of other experts in the community. It’s not an acceptable solution to reject them all without even looking at them, and neither is it acceptable to handle them all using the “usual” process.

Fortunately, if I remember correctly what he told me, he can rule out all but an extremely small percentage of those submissions as being obviously invalid (where “obviously” means he doesn’t have to spend more than 5 minutes looking at them, and can then desk-reject them with an easy conscience and even sometimes provide a bit of feedback to the authors) by applying a simple set of heuristics he developed over time. They go something like:

> - the paper doesn’t use standard notation or terminology, or otherwise show some obvious misunderstanding of the problem or related body of knowledge
> - the paper uses only properties of the Riemann zeta function that are shared by a larger class of functions, for some of which the analogue of the Riemann hypothesis is known to be false
> - the paper proves something that’s actually much stronger than the Riemann hypothesis, and known to be false
>
> [*etc - there are probably more subtle rules of thumb that are still considered by him very trustworthy given his expertise in the subject*]

I believe other experts who are regularly asked to evaluate purported proofs of famous open problems have developed similar heuristics. See for example Scott Aaronson’s “[Ten Signs a Claimed Mathematical Breakthrough is Wrong](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=304)”.

The bottom line is that it is actually quite difficult to come up with a crackpot paper that doesn’t instantly fail a set of obvious sanity checks that experts will know about but the crackpots (or honest amateur mathematicians who are not complete crackpots but simply lack training in the area) don’t. The only people who actually have the ability to “fake” a proof in a way that will require significant effort to detect the fake, are experts themselves, and they usually ([though not always](https://www.math.purdue.edu/people/bio/branges/Papers)) know better and don’t write such papers in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for dredging up Scott Aaronson’s list.   Before anyone complains, these are signs of possible nonsense.  Certainly correct mathematics has been written in Word, for example.  I have given positive referee reports on papers that did not use standard math notation and did not know how to properly use latex.  In one case, the abstract was very clear and paper discussed relevant papers that seems fit for the task at hand.  Well worth the effort to get through, and I gave the author pointers on notation familiar to mathematicians.  The author was not a mathematician.

Comment: @TerryLoring: It's just a list of signs, not a disjunction that implies crackpottery. A good heuristic merely has to be correct most of the time, so that we can combine a few good heuristics to get high confidence of correctness if all the heuristics agree.

Comment: Also, see [Spotting Crankery](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157250/spotting-crankery) on Math SE.

Comment: In the old days, before the four-color theorem was proved, Frank Harary (the author of a standard graph theory text) received so many alleged proofs of this theorem that he prepared form letters (the then-common purple ditto sheets): "Dear ___, Thank you for your proof of the four-color theorem. The first error is on page __. Sincerely, Frank Harary."

Answer (score 18):

Your question has a somehow detailed answer in the following paper:

- Wilfrid Hodges, "An Editor Recalls Some Hopeless Papers", *The Bulletin of Symbolic Logic*, Vol. 4, No. 1, pp. 1-16, 1998, [JSTOR:421003](https://www.jstor.org/stable/421003).

That paper is dedicated to the many papers the journal received refuting Cantor's proof that real numbers and natural numbers have different cardinalities. It analyses the paralogisms contained in these papers, and I think that what it says can be generalised to other situations as well.

But beware that it's not only maths that receives crackpottish submissions: each field has its targets. For instance, in physics, relativity, quantum mechanics and Newton's third law are quite a target. And the submitters may be professionals and not only amateurs. To give you an example, there is a now retired well-known researcher in my field (metrology) who about twenty years ago developed a "theory" which he thinks should substitute Einstein's general relativity. So, about twenty years ago, he started to submit his work first to physics journals, which outright rejected it, and then to conferences in his own field, hoping for acceptance from his colleagues. This caused some headaches to the organizing committees, which anyway rejected his work (as far as I know, it's not been published so far).

So, as far as I know, most editors probably simply shrug those kind of submissions off.

Comment: I just read the paper you recommend, very interesting, thank you! However, neither it nor your answer addresses the OP's question: how does a journal *react* to a crackpot submission. (Unless your answer is that "the editor collects such submissions and distills the lessons learned into a paper".)

Comment: @StephanKolassa It depends on what one intends by _react_. First, at least in my experience, it's the editor who reacts and not the journal, so the reactions are rather personal. The last line covers the reactions of the editors I'm familiar with, at least for my field. There aren't really any more details. The paper instead reports how an editor reacted by analyzing those papers. I'm not aware of different reactions, at least, from the editors I know.

Comment: @StephanKolassa: The cited paper here is **extremely misleading** because the author clearly is unfamiliar with formal deductive systems for basic FOL, in most of which one **is permitted** to give a name to a witness of an existential statement that holds in the current context (whether via ∃-elim or in the process of deriving the conditions for ∃-elim), which is why he calls a logician Beth "mad" in a cited part of Beth's paper despite it being completely correct!! Anyone can either learn a formal FOL deductive system or check with a professional logician to confirm what I say here.

Comment: In particular, Hodges writes "*This last sentence is completely mad. [...] if we know that 'Some individual lives in Neasden', it makes no sense to "agree to give this individual the name 'a' " until we have picked out one such individual. But Beth has done nothing to pick out an individual*". This is absolutely nonsense. Removing the ability to assign a name to an existential witness is equivalent to removing ∃-elim in many FOL deductive systems, which is what is truly mad! Beth has no reason or obligation to show how to 'pick out' an existential witness before being allowed to name it!

Comment: @user21820 I read the paper, and agree with you that that part doesn't seem to be correct. But the rest seems okay. So I'm not sure whether Hodges was showing (unintentionally) the very same fallacy that Hodges is refuting in that section.

Comment: @justhalf: The rest indeed seems okay. I don't think it was unintentional though, as I have seen this misconception regarding ∃-elim come up before from other people. I guess it goes to show that basic FOL is not as trivial as some might believe.

Comment: Ah, I mean it *ironically* shows the same type of mistakes he is trying to showcase. I didn't know that this mistake is quite common, though. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @user21820 I think you're misunderstanding Hodges there. He's writing about stuff that makes no sense when taken **literally**. His point, as I understand it, is that it makes no sense to say "give _this_ individual the name 'a'" when no individual is uniquely determined, rather the correct (even if interpreted quite literally) wording would be to say "let 'a' denote one such individual". (If there is one, and only one, indivdual living in Neasden, then it's of course no problem to say "this". But if there's more than one, whom does "this" refer to?)

Comment: @DanielFischer: It refers (in standard idiomatic English) to "some individual" in the preceding phrase. So, according to standard English, Hodges is wrong. However, I get your point if Hodges is really using non-standard English and complaining that "this" fails to refer (in non-English sense).

Comment: @user21820 I read that paper many years ago, so I don't enter the debate because I'd have to reread it, but about your last comment let me remark that "standard idiomatic English" is frequently understood in different ways also by "standard" native English speakers ;-)

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: Agreed, definitely, but: (1) it is bad to call others "mad" when they use English in widely accepted ways; (2) in this special case I still think that Hodges likely in fact failed to grasp Fitch-style natural deduction. In particular, a statement Q may not be true absolutely, under assumption of Q (as Beth stated) indeed Q is true (contrary to Hodges' first claim of madness), and applying ∃-elim is in fact *the* way in such a system of 'picking out an individual' witness to an ∃-statement (contrary to Hodges' second claim of madness).

Comment: In fact, Hodges clearly implies that Beth is being tripped up; he writes at the end: "*I think I know broadly what are the right answers to these questions, but I don't propose to argue the matter here. The conclusion I want to leave on the table is that the notion of assumptions in arguments is surrounded with serious philosophical puzzles. It can trip up a professional almost as easily as a beginner.*" This is really hogwash; there is no philosophical puzzle if one understands FOL properly, and Beth was not tripped up at all, but Hodges probably was. CC @DanielFischer

Comment: Not just in the conclusion, Hodges wrote earlier: "*Beth's mistakes here seem to me of the same order as any made by our critics of Cantor. He gets away with it because he is a brilliant logician, he writes [sic] a convincing style and we believe his conclusions.*". Nonsense; Beth (as Hodges cited) made no conceptual mistake unlike any Cantor-cranks, and doesn't use a convincing style to convince others, and logicians don't believe him just because he is persuasive... (I'm putting these quotes here for those who cannot access the paywalled article.)

Comment: @user21820 so you are saying the guy who wrote [more than one introductory textbook and a number of other books on logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilfrid_Hodges#Bibliography) "clearly is unfamiliar with formal deductive systems for basic FOL"? Whose [work on logic is rather extensive](http://wilfridhodges.co.uk/), including the relationship between formal semantics and natural language? These are strong claims!

Comment: @DavidRoberts: So what? Just because a logician is familiar with one deductive system (e.g. Hilbert-style) does not mean he/she is familiar with any variant. This ignorance on the part of Hodges is precisely what made him call others "mad". I repeat what I said above; it is bad to call others "mad" when they use English in widely accepted ways; (2) Hodges likely in fact failed to grasp **Fitch-style natural deduction**. You haven't provided any evidence against my detailed explanation.

Comment: @user21820 I didn't claim I did! My links give some context of the subject of discussion, but are not specific enough to rebut your point. I find what you say rather striking, and leave open the option that in what is a sociological paper, the author might be departing from a strictly mathematical register. I have no skin in this game; it might well be true, what you say, even if at first thought it seems unlikely to me.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: What I say **is** true. I have direct first-hand evidence from personal acquaintance with professional logicians such as Stephen Simpson, who is among the **many** logicians that simply do not know much about Fitch-style natural deduction, not to say the specific subtype that supports exactly the intuitive reasoning that Beth **correctly** employs, and which **Hodges** incorrectly and **arrogantly** calls "mad". If you want to ask me for details, you are free to do so, but as far as I can tell your initial comment was not relevant to our discussion.

Comment: In contrast to Hodges, Stephen for example readily admitted that he is unfamiliar with Fitch-style systems, rather than talking nonsense like Hodges. And there are a lot of them, some much closer to ordinary mathematical intuition (that Beth uses) than others. If you don't want to ask me, you can also perform a simple google search on "natural deduction systems", which will allow you to find some starting points such as [this](https://www.sfu.ca/~jeffpell/papers/pelletierNDtexts.pdf) for you to learn about them (more than Hodges).

Comment: @user21820 I cannot argue with your personal experience. But I note that Hodges goes on to say "He gets away with it because ... we believe his conclusions. Though I have him in my sights here, probably most of us have said or written equally crazy things at one time or another." Whatever you feel about the merits of this case, Hodges seems to lump himself in with Beth, as well as most other logicians! Perhaps Hodges is also thinking of Russellian ideas on denotation and description. I don't know. But thanks for the link to the notes!

Answer (score 8):

I'm not a mathematician and I never saw this happen myself, but I heard from a friend that the policy of their department was that if a crackpot paper was received they gave it to a grad student to look over.  The instructions to the grad student were "Read it until you find the first error, then STOP, write a quick summary of the error, and then send it back".  I think the grad students took turns with this.

I don't remember why but apparently their department tended to be a magnet for papers about a particular topic (possibly the Riemann Hypothesis thing, maybe?  I don't remember and am not a mathematician) so any paper coming in on that topic got the above treatment.

Comment: Let's hope the grad students did get properly paid for that!

Comment: @user111388 They surely did - they got a lot of training finding errors :D

Comment: I've heard this attributed to Eric Temple Bell (in Ian Stewart: "The Problems Of Mathematics"), with reference to Fermat's Theorem.

Comment: Precisely this was (part of) my job as a TA. My thesis advisors name was quite established in number theory, attracting a steady stream of papers on the Riemann hypothesis and Collatz conjecture, among others. I got more than fair compensation, but at times I would question my sanity; finding the first error in a text that has no discernible premise, argument or conclusion can be maddening!

Answer (score -5):

There is always the possibility that some gem is hidden in what otherwise seems like a crackpot submissions.  An editor has to accept the that a field can be revolutionized by a single new idea.

A good editor knows most of the ways that thinking goes astray and can categorize wrong ideas easily and tell the author where their own thinking is wrong and respond with stock responses they've already collected.  When they can't do this, either the individual is onto something new or a new path of wrong thinking has been found and the editor can update their set of premade responses.  In either of these cases, the world gains.

If you can't do this, you've succumbed to the hubris that established power often falls into and it serves no one, ultimately.  Honestly, unless it's vandalism or disrespect of the establishment, people should be worthy of responding to.

If we have a society where people are too worthless to give criticism or feedback, then a Doctor of Philosophy has to step up and understand what's going on in their society.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't dealt with crackpot papers in real life.

Comment: This is incorrect. As a grad student I was asked to do peer review for around a dozen crackpot papers, including proofs of RH etc. It's not always easy to pinpoint an error; rather, the reasoning will often be muddled and imprecise, and it won't necessarily be clear what the author is thinking or if they actually understand what they're claiming.

Comment: @MartinArgerami:  I deal with the same problem everyday:  the internet.